# Running Metro App Minimized from Command Line

Tags: windows-10, command-line, modern-ui

Running a metro app from the command line is simple. Ex:

```
start microsoft-edge://
```

Running a non-metro app minimized from the command line is also simple. Ex:

```
start /min notepad.exe
```

However, using `/min` does not work for metro apps. Is there a way to run a metro app minimized?

Answer (score 0):

In the Windows 10 Fall Creators Update 1709 it will be [possible to pass commandline parameters to store apps](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/07/05/command-line-activation-universal-windows-apps/)

> we’ve recently introduced is the ability to activate a UWA from a
>   command line and pass the app arbitrary command-line arguments. This
>   is available to Insiders from build 16226.

So wait until this version gets released in September/October 2017 and for app updates that support this feature.